# Button link doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have this code but the search link doesn't work in Firefox. If I click the box, yes it opens but not the link.

```
<div class="tu_fake">
     <input type="file" name="nfo" onchange="FromNfoo(this.value)" class="tu_fake_file" size="60" />
     <div class="tu_fakeinput">
          <div class="tu_in_fakeinput" id="tuh"></div>
          <a href="#nogo" class="tu_file_button">Search</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You look like you have forgotten to add quotation marks after the onclick function on the button.

Comment: Do you have `FromNfoo` method defined? Have you tried `javascript:FromNfoo(this.value)`?

Comment: Nev: that one was a test, i remove it now.

Comment: Vaishak: will try it.